# Chart.js responsive: animated chart goes decreasing its size until 0

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm having some troubles with chart.js:

the samples in the website load correctly but then the chart starts decreasing its size until 0 like this

[image: chart.js error]

the image corresponds to this [url](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/area/line-boundaries.html) notice how the chart has been reduced until you can only see the X Axis

I did a small sample using chart.js and React and I'm having the same trouble

Do you know what could be the problem  here? My browser is edge in Linux

Thank you

Comment: github open issue: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/10951 seems to be a bug in the chart.js library that only happens when you've some zoom in your browser

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug that appeared in V4, for now to work around this issue you can use version 3.9.1 of the library.